# cakephp 2.1 cannot find() when conditioning on virtualfield

Tags: find, cakephp-2.1

My $condition in find() cannot make use of virtualfield.

I have this virtualfield on my Employee model:

```
        var $virtualFields = array(
            'AgentFullName' => "CONCAT(Employee.id, ' ', Employee.emp_ape_pat, ' ', Employee.emp_ape_mat, ' ', Employee.name)"
        );
```

I'm using this condition to look on two fields, one regular, one virtual (

```
        $idconditions = array(
            'OR' => array(
                'Employee.id LIKE' => $this->passedArgs['valsearch'],
                'Employee.AgentFullName LIKE' => $this->passedArgs['valsearch']
                ));
```

My find returns no record when looking for a valid text that can be found on the virtual field:

```
        $theid = $this->Horario->Employee->find('first', array(
            'fields' => array('Employee.emp_appserial', 'Employee.AgentFullName'),
            'conditions' => $idconditions,
                ));
```

However, the sql_dump seems correct:

When find() looks for an id number:

```
SELECT `Employee`.`emp_appserial`, (CONCAT(`Employee`.`id`, ' ', `Employee`.`emp_ape_pat`, ' ', `Employee`.`emp_ape_mat`, ' ', `Employee`.`name`)) AS `Employee__AgentFullName` FROM `devopm0_5`.`employees` AS `Employee` WHERE ((`Employee`.`id` LIKE 1005) OR ((CONCAT(`Employee`.`id`, ' ', `Employee`.`emp_ape_pat`, ' ', `Employee`.`emp_ape_mat`, ' ', `Employee`.`name`)) LIKE '1005')) LIMIT 1
```

And the find() using last name (returns no record)

```
SELECT `Employee`.`emp_appserial`, (CONCAT(`Employee`.`id`, ' ', `Employee`.`emp_ape_pat`, ' ', `Employee`.`emp_ape_mat`, ' ', `Employee`.`name`)) AS `Employee__AgentFullName` FROM `devopm0_5`.`employees` AS `Employee` WHERE ((`Employee`.`id` LIKE 'SMITH') OR ((CONCAT(`Employee`.`id`, ' ', `Employee`.`emp_ape_pat`, ' ', `Employee`.`emp_ape_mat`, ' ', `Employee`.`name`)) LIKE 'SMITH')) LIMIT 1
```

I wonder why the virtualfield cannot be subject to search.

Can you help?

Thank a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use VirtualFields as SQL Conditions. 
The virtual fields are added to the results after the find is performed, and this is why you cannot condition on them. 
[The Cookbook says](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html):

> These fields cannot be saved, but will be treated like other model fields for read operations. They will be indexed under the model’s key alongside other model fields.

Comment: Thank you so much Borislav; modified my condition to use the regular fields instead of virtuals.